# How to include a class from an included list via Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a class called `Posts` with a navigation property to class `Comment`:

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Comment` class:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public User Commentator { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, comment references a `Post` and a `User`

The user also has a navigation property to comments.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to write a query to select all posts, including comments, then including commentator of the comment, i get the comments, but the commentator keeps returning `null`.

Here is my query:

```
    return _dbContext.Posts
            .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Commentator)
            .Select(x => { PostId = x.Id, Headline = x.Headline, Text = x.Text, Media = x.Image, Comments = x.Comments });
```

And I double checked the data in my database, so I assume it has to do with the `.ThenInclude()` on a list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you initalized List<Comment> Comments?

Comment: [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)

Comment: I believe that EF is confused about what you need. try adding two more properties as follows to the `Comment` class. `public Guid PostId { get; set; }` and `public Guid CommentatorId { get; set; }`

Comment: @IvanStoev My whole Select statement actually looks like this: `.Select(x => new GetPost { PostId = x.Id, Avatar = x.Owner.Avatar, Headline = x.Headline, Text = x.Text, Media = x.Image, Comments = x.Comments });` So I don't think that my Includes are ignored.

Comment: *"If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored."* The `Select` definitely is changing the query to not return the entity type that the query began with. You can remove both `Include` / `ThenInclude` and the result will be the same.

Comment: @IvanStoev okay, tested it and you are right. Do you have an idea how it could be done?

Comment: Unfortunately solving the issue is not that easy as identifying it. If this is the final query (i.e. you don't need `IQueryable` result), you can keep the includes and add `AsEnumerable()` before the `Select`. Otherwise you have to rewrite the query using `Select`s for everything (a lot of repetitive code for selecting each object property).